# Autonumber combo box field up to value from record?

Tags: ms-access

I have a table that initially sets up attributes about part assemblies, where each assembly gets a number of parts. I have a form for a new table where parts for each assembly are entered. I would like to have a combo box fill to a certain number of part numbers, to control the input that the user has. So if an assembly has an entry "#Parts" in a record in "tblAssembly" I would like a combo box "cboPartNumber" in form "Parts" to fill from 1:#Parts for each entry. The

Comment: Do you mean that if #Parts is 5, the combobox should contain the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In order to attribute a number of constant values to a combo box, first set the combo box's `Row Source Type` property to `Value List`. (The default is `Table/Query`).

Now you can enter a list of values in the `Row Source` property like "1;2;3;4;5". If this list is variable, you can do it in a loop like this:

```
Private Sub SetPartNumbers(ByVal n As Long)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim s As String

    s = "1"
    For i = 2 To n
        s = s & ";" & i
    Next i
    Me!Combo1.RowSource = s
End Sub
```